Proof of Hadamard transform on $N$ qubits

Q:$$H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|-|1\rangle\langle 1|)$$
Show that
$$ H^{\otimes N}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^N}}\sum_{x,y\in\{0,1\}^N}(-1)^{x\cdot y}|x\rangle\langle y| $$

By induction, we get that
$$\begin{aligned}H^{\otimes (N+1)}&=\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\sum_{x,y}(-1)^{x,y}|x\rangle\langle y|\bigg)\otimes\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle\langle0|+|1\rangle\langle 0|+|0\rangle\langle 1|-|1\rangle\langle 1|)\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\sum_{x,y}(-1)^{\overline{x0}\cdot\overline{y0}}|x0\rangle\langle y0|+(-1)^{\overline{x1}\cdot\overline{y0}}|x1\rangle\langle y0|+(-1)^{\overline{x0}\cdot\overline{y1}}|x0\rangle\langle y1|+(-1)^{\overline{x1}\cdot\overline{y1}}|x1\rangle\langle y1|
\\&=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}\sum_{x',y'\in\{0,1\}^{N+1}}(-1)^{x'\cdot y'}|x'\rangle\langle y'|\end{aligned}$$
But I'm not sure that this step is right
$$ |xi\rangle\langle yj|=|x\rangle\langle y|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j|\qquad i,j=0,1
$$

Updated
So at last we just need to prove this equation, which is for any vector $|mn\rangle=|m\rangle\otimes|n\rangle$
$$
\bigg(|x\rangle\otimes|j\rangle\bigg)\bigg(\langle y|\otimes\langle i|\bigg)|mn\rangle = \bigg(|x\rangle\langle y|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j|\bigg)|mn\rangle
$$
In fact $$\begin{aligned}
\text{LHS} & = \langle yi | mn \rangle \bigg(|x\rangle\otimes|j\rangle\bigg)\\
\text{RHS} & =  \bigg(|x\rangle\langle y|\otimes|i\rangle\langle j|\bigg)\bigg(|m\rangle\otimes|n\rangle\bigg)\\
&\qquad \text{using definition of tensor product}(A \otimes B) (C \otimes D) = AC \otimes BD\\
& = \bigg( \langle y | m\rangle | x \rangle \bigg) \otimes \bigg( \langle i | n\rangle | j \rangle \bigg)
\end{aligned}$$
It's obvious that $\langle yi | mn \rangle =1$ iff $y=m$ and $i=n$ which means that $\langle y | m \rangle =1$ and $\langle i | n \rangle =1$.

Yes, that step is correct. and the whole thing holds together (assuming you've explicitly mentioned the base case).

But how to prove this step? I try to expand $$|xi\rangle\langle yj|=(|x\rangle\otimes|i\rangle)(\langle y|\otimes\langle j|)$$ but still get confused.

@KrystalJustin one of the property of kronekcer product is $$(A \otimes B) \cdot (C \otimes D) = AC \otimes BD,.$$ See Chapter 4 in this.

It's not really something you prove (depending on what aspect is causing you confusion). It's just a definition of the notation: $|xi\rangle=|x\rangle\otimes|i\rangle$. Then you follow it up with @FDGod 's identity

@ FDGod I cannot find the identity in the book. But I know that this identity is right when $A$ and $B$ are linear operators and $C$ and $D$ are vectors in hillbert space due to the definition of tensor product. It's a pity that $|x\rangle$ and $|i\rangle$ are not linear operators. So it needs the proof of that special case.

$|xi\rangle\langle yj| = |x\rangle\langle j| \otimes |i\rangle\langle j|$ is true just by definition of the kronecker product. By the way, the statement that $|x\rangle$ and $|i\rangle$ are not linear operators isn't exactly true, they are linear maps from a $d$-dimensional space to a $1$-dimensional space, i.e. a $d \times 1$ matrix. We can see that the product in the LHS $(A \otimes B) \cdot (C \otimes D)$ is a $1 \times d^2$ matrix multiplied by a $d^2 \times 1$ matrix. By the property of block matrices, its straightforward to show that this product is exactly the RHS.

@xzkxyz You're right. I only consider the definition in the square matrix case. Thanks for your answer!
